# reset html form input using google.script.run

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I need help to figure out how to refresh an input value after updating a select within an html form that I'm using to populate a Google spreadsheet.

code:

```
function description(item){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DATA');
    var cell = sheet.getRange('ITEM');

    cell.setFormula('=VLOOKUP(' + item + ';ITEMS!$C$2:$AE;29;FALSE)');

    return cell.getValue();

}
```

HTML:

```
...

<select id="SKU" onchange="update();"><?!= Drop_SKU();?></select>

<input id="description" value="<?!= ss.getRange('ITEM').getDisplayValue();?>"> 

...

<script>

  window.update=function(){

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var parameter = document.getElementById('SKU').value
      var newValue = google.script.run.description(parameter);

      document.getElementById('description').value = newValue;

  }
```

As a result, description function runs perfectly, but leads to set undefined value to the input "description".

What am I missing?

I'll apreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google.script.run has two pieces to determine how what to do after the Server Side code is run:
.withSuccessHandler(successFunction)
.withFailureHandler(failedFunction)

If the server side function runs with no errors, the function defined by withSuccessHandler will run, and any returned value is passed to that function.  If an error occurs, the function defined by withFailureHandler will be executed.  So your script portion of the HTML will look like this:

```
    <script>

      window.update=function(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var parameter = document.getElementById('SKU').value
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showNewValue).withFailureHandler(functionFailed).description(parameter);
  }

  function showNewValue(newValue){
      document.getElementById('description').value = newValue;
  }

  function functionFailed(error){
      document.getElementById('description').value = 'Error returned: ' + error;
  }
</script>
```

Note that I have not looked at the rest of the code to see if there are other problems.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, sorry but this code provides no action at all. Nothing happens. Neither 'description' runs on the server side.

Comment: Sorry about that.  If you can, edit my post to fix the typing mistake so it is accurate for others.

Comment: Nevermind Karl, as the mistake was mine instead of yours, as I changed some variables names from your code. Thanks again.